# "The array is only written to, never read from" error showing in Java code

Tags: java

I've been trying to polish up on some Java and I'm trying to refresh the basics so I've been working through the Sam's 24 hour java book. One of the projects to familiarize yourself with describing objects gives the code as follows:

```
package com.java24hours;

public class GremlinLab {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        int numGremlins = Integer.parseInt(arguments[0]);
        if (numGremlins > 0) {
            Gremlin[] gremlins = new Gremlin[numGremlins];
            for (int i = 0; i < numGremlins; i++) {
                gremlins[i] = new Gremlin();
            }
            System.out.println("There are " + Gremlin.getGremlinCount()
                + " gremlins.");
        }
    }
}
```

The error "The array is only written to, never read from" is showing upon compilation in the 7th line:

```
Gremlin[] gremlins = new Gremlin[numGremlins];
```

and I can't figure out for the life of me why this is not working! Apologies if I'm being stupid but any help will be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

Sorry quick edit to add the other class I haven't mentioned!!

I have also got the following class:

```
package com.java24hours;

public class Gremlin {
    static int gremlinCount = 0;

    public Gremlin() {
        gremlinCount++;
    }

    static int getGremlinCount() {
        return gremlinCount;
    }
}
```

I then specified the command-line arguments by customizing the project configuration.

Last Edit!!...
Thanks very much everyone, I really appreciate it. I'm using an IDE and moved the classes to the source packages folder rather than the 'com.java24hours' package....and my original codes have worked fine?! Clearly I'm very much a novice! Thanks again all :)

Comment: What are you using the array for? You populate it, and then the program ends.

Comment: Two minor remarks: this is a warning, not an error. --- You can remove the array and just call `new Gremlin()` in the loop. This should remove the warning.

Comment: You fill the array, then never do anything with it. I suspect that `Gremlin.getGremlinCount()` is supposed to do something with it, but it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks all, problem seems to be solved! I've edited my original post - thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a warning, not an error. You can safely ignore it and your program will function as you intend.

The warning is because you are creating an array and filling it with elements. But then you never actually use the array nor the elements of that array for anything. For example, you could do

```
System.out.println("There are " + gremlins.length + " gremlins.");
```

to print the length of the array. This will remove the warning.

Better yet, if you are writing this as an exercise to learn about `static` methods and variables, just don't use an array at all.

Comment: Also the array itself is not being used, not only its elements.

Comment: @f1sh Oh...you are right. I misread `Gremlin.getGremlinCount()` as using the array.

Comment: Just a side note (it's not even a jab at this answer) for when the OP reads this -- if you do decide to use `gremlins.length` instead of `Gremlin.getGremlinCount()`, for the print statement, the code that keeps track of the gremlin count with a static variable will then be unused. However, you may not get a warning in this case, as some IDEs don't generate warnings for public methods and variables.

Comment: @HylianPikachu Good point. The OP's code looks like an exercise to learn about `static`, so the array isn't even needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with the elements of the `gremlins` array. ie nowhere does your code do something like `gremlins[i].someMethod()`, but  it's only a warning.